# jQuery vTicker - Pause:true Resumes on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, ticker, news-ticker, vticker

I have successfully implemented the jQuery [vTicker plugin](http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/), along with 'previous,' 'next,' and 'pause' link functionality. When I click Pause, the ticker does pause.

The problem is when the ticker is paused, if you mouse-over the ticker, it resumes. You can see this happen on the [demo page](http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/methods/) of this site I posted above (click the pause button in the demo, then mouse-over the ticker below it).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Matt - this issue has now been fixed and the latest version 1.13 includes this fix. I have a test that covers this issue too now.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found that an issue had been posted on the author's [github page](https://github.com/richhollis/vticker) for this problem. The poster had also resolved his issue and had posted the code. You can find the fixed code here: https://github.com/richhollis/vticker/pull/6